# Reading and writing file from a runnable jar with no path specified

Tags: java, jar

If I am a running a runnable jar and have the code:

```
File txtfile = new File("sampleText.txt");
```

Would the file be created? If so where would `sampleText.txt` be created? In Eclipse, this would be created in the working directory. I have read that it is not possible to write within a jar, if so what would happen to this file? Will JAVA create this file elsewhere?

Also, if it was created, will I be able to read it?

Comment: why don't you write a little program to test it out for yourself? it will surely answer your question. :)

Comment: @KinCheung I didn't notice it was being created! Wow, that was dumb! I had been having an error in reading the file and that made me believe the file wasn't being created. I guess I should be more organized with my files then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working directory in this instance would be whichever directory the jar is in. So, yes the file would be created, and yes you'll be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code line for creating new file.

```
File txtfile = new File("sampleText.txt");
```

You haven't specify locstion, that means the place that this code is runnig, is the place `sampleText.txt` is created.

After you created jar file. jar means you compressing the all the code. The code for creating `sampleText.txt` is also there. So if you created your jar elsewhere, that the place your file created.

Note: unless you specified a location, like:

```
File file = new File("C:\\somefile\\sampleText.txt");
```

If you specify a location like this, your file should be that location no matter where your jar is.